# Use nonlinear mixed model for binomial distributed data

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, nonlinear-regression, lme4-nlme

I frequently use this model to test catch efficiency and size selection properties of a given trawl fishing gear:

\begin{equation}
\theta(l)=\frac{s\times r(l)}{(1-s)+s\times r(l)}
\end{equation}

where $\theta(l)$ denotes the expected catch rate in the test gear ($T$), which has been fishing in parallel with a non-selective gear (the control gear with blind meshes,$C$). The parameters affecting $\theta(l)$ are:

- **Split parameter** $(s)$: It defines the probability of a fish to enter in $T$ ($s$) or in $C$ ($1-s$), $s\in\{0,1\}$
- **Fish size selection** ($r(l)$): It defines the likelihood of fish retention in $T$. This likelihood is conditioned to fish body length, therefore it describes the size selection in $T$. Fish size selection is used to be defined using the logit function:

\begin{equation}
r(l)=\frac{exp(\beta_1+\beta_2\times l )}{1+exp(\beta_1+\beta_2\times l )} 
\end{equation}

Overall, there is a total of 3 parameters to be estimated ($s$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$). We use nonlinear regression techniques to estimate such parameters by maximizing the binomial log-likelihood function:

\begin{equation}
\sum_l(N_{l}^T\times \log\theta(l)+N_{l}^C\times \log(1-\theta(l))) 
\end{equation}

where $N_{l}^T$ is the number of fishes per length-class caught in $T$, and $N_{l}^C$ is the numbers caught in $C$.

During a normal experiment, we deploy the pair of gears ($T$ and $C$) several times to perform parallel fishing. To account for the between-haul variation, we use the bootstrap (using a resampling scheme based on resampling between hauls and fishes within hauls) to estimate the errors of $s$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

I´m wondering if it´s possible to shift towards a nonlinear mixed modeling approach, where the hauls are considered as a random component. At the moment I only could find such approach by using least squares as minimization criteria. But I could not find a way to keep using the log-likelihood binomial mass function as target criteria.

Thank you beforehand for any comment or guidance.

Comment: You certainly can, but GNLMMs (generalized nonlinear mixed models) can be challenging to implement. [AD Model Builder](http://admb-project.org) is widely used in fisheries for nonlinear/mixed modeling, but has a steep learning curve ...

Comment: Thank you Ben for your reply. I ´m not familiar with ADMB, and the steep learning curve prevents me to dive into this issue now. I did not use the classic least squares approach as might produce biased/unexpected results.